# eclipse creates module-info file in executable jar with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I had a pom file and created jar with eclipse export option and log4j was working fine. After adding the dependency `selenium-java` the export creates `module-info` file in the jar and log4j no longer works. And `Log4j-config.xsd` becomes empty in the jar.

As my project has JDK  1.8 configured and selenium also requires 1.8 / later, could not identify the cause.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Very likely the `module-info.class` has not been created by Eclipse, but comes from a dependency (what's in the `module-info.class` file?). Exporting as an executable JAR means to include all dependencies in a single JAR (also called fat JAR or uber JAR). When using the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules) by having your own `module-info.java` file, a fat JAR does not work since each module has to be in its own JAR. When using Maven, better build the JAR(s) with Maven.

Comment: ok. Will build with maven. module-info.class contains single line:  // INTERNAL ERROR //

Comment: Using Maven is not the solution for your problem. Your problem is either the use of a fat JAR where this is not possible or something else that is unrelated to the `module-info.class`. `// INTERNAL ERROR //` sound like you opened it in the wrong editor. `.class` files contains bytecode and cannot be opened in a text editor.

Comment: I opened module-info.class with JD only.

Comment: The selenium site says it requires Java 11. Does that not apply to the selenium-java version you're using?

Comment: "Selenium will stop supporting Java 8 on September 30, 2023" - Till now it is JDK 8 only.

Comment: I got jars builts with maven.